# How to display that given address is not on google map

Tags: php, google-maps

I have two input box:

```
<input name="adrs" id="adrs" type="text">
<input name="city" id="city" type="text">
```

Now I want when user write this, **is there any way by which i can tell the user that given address is not on google map?**  Any simple method , I am  using `EasyGoogleMap.class.php` class.  Please suggest me any jquery method to show the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to geocode the address and analyze the returned data. I don't know what class you're using - maybe it already contains a geocoding function. If not, [**this article**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html) gives a complete rundown on how to program this in PHP.

The returned address will contain a `accuracy` field.

The accuracy codes that will interest you most are

```
7   Intersection level accuracy.
8   Address level accuracy.
9   Premise (building name, property name, shopping center, etc.) level accuracy.
```

If you get  a code 8 and above, you can safely assume the address is on Google Maps. If it's below, it's not, or not exactly.

You can look up all accuracy codes [**here**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoAddressAccuracy).